# JPA Entity and relations OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany - good practice

Tags: java, jpa, entity

Analyzing some tutorials I found diffrent practice in defining Java object and collection relations with OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany annotations in entity classes. I have two doubts about that:

1. What type of collation should I use: Set or List?

for example:

```
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

or

```
private List<Employee> employees;
```

2. Should I create object in entity?

for example:

```
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

or

```
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

When I'm creating a new object the second solution is better, beacause I'll not get a NullPointerException when I use employees collection, but when I'm getting an object from DB in my opinion will be created two object one on createing new entity and second when setEmplyees is called.

What are the best practices in this cases?

Answer (score 2):

**For 1.**

My suggestion would be to use List instead of Set:

```
private List<Employee> employees;
```

**my motivation:**

A List would behave in a way that I would expect. If the List references database entries that may contain duplicates, the list property would be the proper way to map them to the java world.

If it is safe to assume that the database entries never contain duplicates, a Set may be chosen as well.

Use the collection type that mirrors the state of the database in the best possible way.

**For 2.**

I would advice to always instantiate the collections in order to prevent a NullPointerException

```
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

**my motivation:**

It is true what you said above. One instance of HashSet will be created on instantiation of your entity and another one when `setEmployees()` is called.

However, in almost all cases the loss of memory and performance here would be negligible. The garbage collector will take care of this.

The null safety argument does outweigh the other argument, imho.

Answer (score 0):

**List vs Set**

You choose depending on the behavior you need:

- list: typically guarantees order (depending on the underlying implementation ie ArrayList), for example respecting the order of the records loaded from the DB
- set: no order is guaranteed but it does not allow duplicates

**Initialize collections**

Both situations are fine IMO.

If undefined (null) then you need to take care of possible NPE when you create an instance of the container object yourself.
When the object is JPA loaded it would include eventually a not null value.

Comment: *for example respecting the order of the records loaded from the DB* You JPA provider should do the same for sets by using a `LinkedHashSet`implementation when `@OrderBy` is specified on the association.